# The type name 'DaysInMonth' does not exist in the type 'DateTime' [Assembly-CSharp]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and wanted to find the days of the month, but my Visual Code is saying that there's no method of DateTime.DaysInMonth()

```
The type name 'DaysInMonth' does not exist in the type 'DateTime' [Assembly-CSharp]
```

Anyone knows why???

Comment: It seems to think you're treating it as a *type*. Please show the code you're trying to use. (Always, always show the code that's producing the error...)

Comment: Are you after the day in the month on a given day, or are you after how many days are in that given month?

Comment: Sorry about that, i've already solved it 2 days after I posted it. I don't know why but DateTime.DaysInMonth() cannot be accepted so I just used DateTime.Today.Month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method DaysInMonth has two parameters (month and year). Have a look at the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=net-6.0)

So you have to call the method like `DateTime.DaysInMonth(04, 2022)` for example.